# Replace character unless it is preceded by a substring

Tags: bash, sed

I have a large number of files with names like

`name.of.file.to.change.fastq`.

I would like to change all the periods in the name to underscores except for the last period that comes before "fastq" to get

`name_of_file_to_change.fastq`

I've seen an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609659/how-to-use-sed-to-find-and-replace-items-only-if-the-match-is-not-bound-by-lett?rq=1) using sed that replaces a character unless there is a certain character that comes after it but I haven't been able to figure out how to expand the search for a single character into a substring.

Comment: `/\.fastq/{s/./_/g; s/_fastq/.fastq/;}` ? Change all dots, and then revert only for "fastq"?

Comment: Thanks. I like that idea. I'm still a bit new to bash. What do the curly brackets do in sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` is overkill for this.  Try this Bash (+`mv`) code:

```
shopt -s nullglob   # Globs that match nothing expand to nothing
shopt -s dotglob    # Globs can expand to names that start with '.'

for file in *.*.fastq ; do
    base=${file%.fastq}     # Remove '.fastq' suffix
    newbase=${base//./_}    # Change all '.' to '_'
    newfile=$newbase.fastq  # Add back the '.fastq' suffix

    # If the new filename already exists, issue a warning and don't clobber it
    if [[ -e $newfile || -L $newfile ]] ; then
        printf 'Warning: "%s" exists.  Skipping "%s"\n' "$newfile" "$file" >&2
    else
        mv -- "$file" "$newfile"
    fi
done
```

See [Parameter expansion [Bash Hackers Wiki]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) for explanations of `${file%.fastq}` and `${base//./_}`.

Answer (score 1):

With the perl-flavoured [`rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/file-rename.1p.html), you can do

```
rename -n 's/\.fastq$//; tr/./_/; $_.=".fastq"' *.fastq
# or
rename -n 'tr/./_/; s/_(?=fastq$)/./' *.fastq
```

Answer (score 1):

Try echo first begore executing the mv:

```
echo mv ${f} $(tr '.' '_' <<< "${f%.*}").${f##*.}
# When ok
mv ${f} $(tr '.' '_' <<< "${f%.*}").${f##*.}
```